# PJL commands added to a PCL file breaks barcodes when output to a printer. Possible encoding issue

Tags: c#, encoding, printer-control-language, pjl

I am using Redmon Port Redirector to save a PCL stream to file.

I then, using C#, add some PJL commands to the file and save it back to disk.

Then using LPR send the document to the printer.

What happens is that all text prints fine but any barcodes in the file are really messed up and I would say scrunched together. If I do not add any PJL commands then the barcodes print as expected.

Here are the files [before](http://ge.tt/5ZCBo3p1/v/0?c) and [after](http://ge.tt/66Cfo3p1/v/0)

My guess is that there are some problems with the encoding, but I am unsure where to go from here.